# Sharing Extensions in IOS Apps

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, sharing, ios-app-extension

I am new to the overall iOS Programming - Swift. I am wondering that if I create a project in xCode6 and then I would like to share an image that I took from my project for example to evernote, google drive, messages, email, facebook, twitter,so on and so on.

So, how would I do that? Is it something, I need to enable from xcode6 for each sharing extension or I need to implement swift code to enable these sharing extensions?

What kind of configurations I might needs to change to get sharing extensions (mentioned above) enabled? Or what kind of code changes in a project are possible? Are there any examples or samples out there with the instructions that I can look into and see how they implement into xcode6.

I never work with the sharing extensions before, so any knowledge that can be shared will be a great resource for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the record, you must do more research before asking to avoid downvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Use the Xcode Share Template**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ShareSheet.html).

There is a lot of tutorials online to know how to make share extensions using Swift, here are some of them and some good articles about extensions you should know too :

- [Building a Simple Share Extension in iOS 8 App](http://www.appcoda.com/ios8-share-extension-swift/)
- [Xcode 6 Tutorial: iOS 8 Simple Share Extension in Swift](http://www.veasoftware.com/tutorials/2014/10/8/xcode-6-tutorial-ios-8-simple-share-extension-in-swift)
- [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ShareSheet.html)
- [Share extensions in iOS 8: Explained](http://www.imore.com/sharing-ios-8-explained)

Even you could do it in code too in the following way:

```
@IBAction func shareSheet(sender: AnyObject){

    let firstActivityItem = "Hey, check out this mediocre site that sometimes posts about Swift!"

    let secondActivityItem : NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "http://www.dvdowns.com/")!

    let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
    activityItems: [firstActivityItem, secondActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)

    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
      UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
      UIActivityTypePrint,
      UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
      UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
      UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
      UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
      UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
      UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo
    ]

    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The above code only works for iPhones because for iPad you need to specify the `sourceView` and show it as a popover in the following way:

```
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = (sender as! UIButton)
```

The above line must be put in just after you init the `activityViewController` and it should be work.

I hope this help you.

Comment: @alfresco_developer I just updated more my answer I thought can help you more than before.

Comment: Thanks @Victor, I will try with code as well. Thanks again for the great help.

Comment: You're welcome, In a few days I'll going to create a post in my blog with all the info related your question. I''l update the answer when it's done.